# add mandatory property to an existing nodeType

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I want to add mandatory property to an existing NodeType that already has some nodes. I specified default value for new field but when new cdn goes to register below exception occurred:

```
org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException: OakConstraint0021: /contents[[myNamespace:folder]]: Mandatory property myNamespace:newField not found in a new node
```

and here is property definition:

```
- myNamespace:newField (string) ='system' mandatory
```

How can I add mandatory property to an existing nodeType that has some nodes?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the classic database field approach (**hint: multiple-steps**):  add new property as optional, then populate all the existing rows, then you can make it mandatory.

You can't make something required if there is existing content nodes that don't have the (new) property.